# Is it possible to specify a general spark schema whilst still allowing variability within nested columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a series of raw json files that I would like to convert into spark dataframes so they can be processed and used by analysts. If possible I would like to manually specify a spark schema to speed along processing.

However, whilst the outermost layer of these json objects have a consistent structure, one of the columns (data) contains further nested information that needs to be maintained for further processing

```
# example 1:
{
    "column1": "always present",
    "column2": "always present",
    "column3": "always present",
    "data": {
        "columnA": "sometimes present",
    },
}

# example 2:

{
    "column1": "always present",
    "column2": "always present",
    "column3": "always present",
    "data": {
        "columnB": "sometimes present",
        "metadata": { 
            "columnAlpha": "sometimes present" 
        }
    },
}

# example 3:

{
    "column1": "always present",
    "column2": "always present",
    "column3": "always present",
    "data": {
        "columnB": "sometimes present",
        "columnC": "sometimes present",
        "metadata": { 
            "columnBeta": "sometimes present",
            "columnGamma": "sometimes present",
        }
    },
}

# etc...
```

I can manually specify a schema that ignores or overrides the values stored in `"data"`, but I wonder if there is a "best-of-both" worlds approach where I can speed up processing of the outermost layer whilst maintaining a view of the items in `"data"`.

```
my_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("column1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("column2", StringType(), True),
        StructField("column3", StringType(), True),
        # is there anything like a wildcard I can use to allow a range of values?
        StructField("data", StructType([StructField("*", StringType(), True),]), True),
    ]
)

df = spark.read.schema(my_schema).json("path/to/json")
df.show()

# would return

+-------+----------+-------+----+
|column1|   column2|column3|data|
+-------+----------+-------+----+
|    1.1|fruit/json|"apple"|  []|
|    1.1|drink/json|"candy"|  []|
|    1.1| meal/json|"pizza"|  []|
+-------+----------+-------+----+

# whereas I would like

+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
|column1|   column2|column3|            data|
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
|    1.1|fruit/json|"apple"|[abcde, 1234,...|
|    1.1|drink/json|"candy"|[fghij, 5678,...|
|    1.1| meal/json|"pizza"|[klmno, 9101,...|
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
```

Ultimately it's not the end of the world if it can't be done, I can use `where` clauses to split up the dataframe and then process each category of json separately downstream, but it would still help speed up processing.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is less complex than I thought, Spark will output nested columns as `null` when they're not present (which is adequate for my use-case). So I've simply defined the structure down to all the columns of interest, and if that column exists it will provide a value for that data.

Alternatively, if you're worried about losing potentially valuable data downstream with a strict enforced schema, you can specify the variable column as `stringType`. Later you could use a udf to extract the values using a conversion from json.

An example of the second approach can be found here: https://kontext.tech/column/spark/284/pyspark-convert-json-string-column-to-array-of-object-structtype-in-data-frame **note**: I am not the author of the linked piece.